# three tables relation order is correct but values are false

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join, query-performance

i have those tables

```
     table1
|  id  |  name  |
|  1   |  axe   |
|  2   |  bow   |
|  3   |  car   |
|  4   |  dart  |


        table2                                        table3
|  t1_id  |  number  |                        |  t1_id  |  letter  |
|  1      |  5       |                        |  1      |  a       |
|  1      |  6       |                        |  1      |  b       |
|  1      |  2       |                        |  1      |  c       |
|  2      |  2       |                        |  2      |  a       |
|  2      |  2       |                        |  2      |  c       |
|  2      |  3       |                        |  2      |  r       |
|  3      |  8       |                        |  3      |  y       |
|  3      |  3       |                        |  3      |  i       |
|  3      |  1       |                        |  3      |  a       |
|  4      |  8       |                        |  4      |  a       |
|  4      |  9       |                        |  4      |  b       |
|  4      |  10      |                        |  4      |  c       |
```

and **table1(id) is linked with table2(t1_id), table3(t1_id)**

i run it to get them order by the **highest letter_count** match then by the **highest average_number** match to get this **proper** result http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69086b/8/0

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  t1.name

FROM 
  table1 t1

INNER JOIN 
  table2 t2
    ON t2.t1_id = t1.id

LEFT JOIN 
  table3 t3
    ON t3.t1_id = t1.id
      AND t3.letter IN ('a', 'b', 'c')

GROUP BY
  t1.id

ORDER BY
  COUNT(t3.letter) DESC,
  AVG(t2.number) DESC
```

---

```
|  id  |  name  |
|  4   |  dart  |
|  1   |  axe   |
|  2   |  bow   |
|  3   |  car   |
```

and everything is working ok

---

but when i wanted to check if there is any problems with the query i decided to check the **letter_count** and **avg_number** so i used this query

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  t1.name, 
  COUNT(t3.letter) AS letter_count, 
  AVG(t2.number) AS avg_number

FROM 
  table1 t1

INNER JOIN 
  table2 t2
    ON t2.t1_id = t1.id

LEFT JOIN 
  table3 t3
    ON t3.t1_id = t1.id
      AND t3.letter IN ('a', 'b', 'c')

GROUP BY
  t1.id

ORDER BY
  letter_count DESC,
  avg_number DESC
```

what i expected the result to be was

```
|  id  |  name  |  letter_count  |  avg_number   |
|  4   |  dart  |  3             |  9            |
|  1   |  axe   |  3             |  4.3333333333 |
|  2   |  bow   |  2             |  2.3333333333 |
|  3   |  car   |  1             |  4            |
```

but the result i got was http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69086b/3/0

```
|  id  |  name  |  letter_count  |  avg_number   |
|  4   |  dart  |  9             |  9            |
|  1   |  axe   |  9             |  4.3333333333 |
|  2   |  bow   |  6             |  2.3333333333 |
|  3   |  car   |  3             |  4            |
```

---

what surprised me was the multiplied row of **letter_count** which can be solved by **derived queries** but i don't want to select the **letter_count** or **number_average** i only want to **ORDER BY** them

does keeping the query like it is with **ORDER BY** only wont affect the query performance or should i still use derived queries even if i don't need to select the data values since the order is correct anyway or would derived query be faster in huge tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've really asked 2 questions here:

1. Does the `ORDER BY` clause affect query performance
2. Why is my letter count not as expected

Either way, to evaluate the `ORDER BY` clause, the expressions need to be evaluated so that the order can be determined. In your first example you need to specify the expressions because those columns are not contained within the `SELECT` statement.

However in your second query you have selected the columns that you want to order by and  because `ORDER BY` is evaluated *AFTER* the entire query has been processed, you can simply use the column *ALIAS* in the `ORDER BY` clause, instead of executing the function again.

> some RDBMS query optimisers will convert your expressions in the `ORDER BY` statements to use the column alias for you IF you are ordering on expressions that exist in your `SELECT` clause

You were right to do this however, your letter count expression is not current due to the duplicates in the response.

You can simply change the `COUNT` expression to use a distinct clause to only count unique values.

```
COUNT(DICTINCT t3.letter)
```

This makes your original query now look like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.id, 
  t1.name

FROM 
  table1 t1

INNER JOIN 
  table2 t2
    ON t2.t1_id = t1.id

LEFT JOIN 
  table3 t3
    ON t3.t1_id = t1.id
      AND t3.letter IN ('a', 'b', 'c')

GROUP BY
  t1.id

ORDER BY
  COUNT(DICTINCT t3.letter) DESC,
  AVG(t2.number) DESC
```

Comment: Remove the group by statement and include `t3.letter` and `t2.number` in your select, that should highlight why count in your original query is returning a different value to what you are expecting. Over a large record set, this value being wrong might result in a different order than what you are expecting. Again it's up to you if the order is important at all

Comment: what would have happened if i didn't added the `DISTINCT` and left it as it is in the future with millions of records? and should i fix the response of duplicates with derived queries or no need to fix it in my case of "only ordering"?

Comment: This is a simple enough query, I suspect using sub-queries or derived queries would both complicate this query and make it slower over a much larger record set. It will depend on your derived query though. If you are not happy with the performance of this query then make your derived query and compare the execution times, we can talk theory but the actual execution plan and times will be greatly affected by your specific query implementation, schema and server resources

Answer (score 0):

This retrieves what you require:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, count(a.letter) letter_count, avg(a.number) avg_number
FROM( SELECT   
t1.id, 
t1.name, 
t3.letter, 
t2.number--,  
FROM 
table1 t1

INNER JOIN 
table2 t2
ON t2.t1_id = t1.id

INNER JOIN 
table3 t3
ON t3.t1_id = t1.id
    AND t3.letter IN ('a', 'b', 'c')

GROUP BY
t1.id,  t1.name,  t3.letter, t2.number) a GROUP BY id, a.name

ORDER BY
letter_count DESC,
avg_number DESC
```

Comment: i refactored it and it worked but with the 2nd query results http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69086b/17/0